# issue related to showing data in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

models.py

```
class ReportType(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def where(request):
    user=request.user
    try:
        report = Report.objects.get(user=user.id)
    except:
        report = None
    reporttype = ReportType.objects.all()
        .          .        .
        .          .        .
    return render(request, 'incident/where.html',
        {
            'newreport_menu': True,
            'reporttype':reporttype
    })
```

It is giving me the output in this form `[<ReportType: Bike parking>, <ReportType: car parking>]` .How to display the values like this "Bike parking,car parking".

Comment: Are you showing this in template? How?

Comment: In template i am showing like this {{ reporttype }}

Comment: Does the answer didn't work? If not, show the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) template tag

```
{% for rt in reporttype %}
    {{ rt.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: +1, `{{r}}` would be sufficient too.. since `__unicode__` is set to `self.title`

Comment: Yep true, I try to avoid using just the plain object as a template variables for the inevitable cases where I forget to write a `__unicode__`.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony,Can you please check this SO question and quide me how to perform.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652075/showing-the-checked-item-alone-without-check-box

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony,have you checked my last question